# Не броская на первый взгляд сущность – как реализовано это шаманство?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Здесь https://websemantics.uk/ размещены ссылки в виде блоков и внутри каждого блока своя иконка. При hover на блок/ссылку, у заполненных цветом линий и внутренних форм иконок появляется визуальный шум. Что это js, canvas; как это сделано?

Comment: Это svg и css .

Comment: да мне понравилось тоже

Comment: https://codepen.io/JoyZi/pen/Mrrrgg вот посмотри не одно и тоже но похоже

Comment: Demon __ ANT, да, интересно тоже, понравилось что ты показал. Уразумел, как увидеть через отладчик –  Darth прав это svg. Есть сервисы которые помогу сделать такое или ручками делать нужно?

Comment: @dupre есть два выхода либо ручками деалешь сам как хочешь либо берешь готовое в сайтах которое делал другой как хотель

Comment: Понятно, буду разбираться. Спасибки за участие, я благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно просто паттерн при `hover` делаем прозрачным такой же элемент а под ним как раз в этом патерне нагодится гифка ..всё

```js
var colorArray = ["transparent", "#000"]; 
var i = 0;
var rect = document.getElementById("rec");
var elem = document.getElementById("elem");
elem.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  rect.style.fill = colorArray[i];
  i++;
  if (i > colorArray.length - 1) {
    i = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
#elem {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    id="svg8" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 5000 5000">
  <defs>
    <pattern patternTransform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,-3126.0325,-1749.9689)" id="pattern1840" xlink:href="#pattern1112"/>
    <pattern
       id="pattern1112"
       patternTransform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,-2273.8855,-482.95559)"
       height="3441.5641"
       width="5768.9556"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         y="5.2735594e-013"
         x="-1.3855583e-013"
         xlink:href="http://s2.favim.com/orig/150624/black-gif-grunge-white-Favim.com-2848003.gif"
         preserveAspectRatio="none"
         height="3441.5642"
         width="5768.9556" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <g transform="translate(3179.6234,879.28318)">

    <path
       id="rect1835"
       d="m -3178.4626,-878.65143 c 395.1946,43.80854 859.5117,294.9846 1141.7753,0 -257.6021,277.96031 -266.9249,555.92061 0,833.880922 -372.609,-62.265192 -717.3232,-342.110282 -1141.7753,0 251.8585,-277.960312 226.8166,-555.920612 0,-833.880922 z"
       style="fill:url(#pattern1840);" />
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:#000000;"
       d="m -3178.4626,-878.65143 c 395.1946,43.80854 859.5117,294.9846 1141.7753,0 -257.6021,277.96031 -266.9249,555.92061 0,833.880922 -372.609,-62.265192 -717.3232,-342.110282 -1141.7753,0 251.8585,-277.960312 226.8166,-555.920612 0,-833.880922 z"
       id="rec" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: толко запускается ни сразу - не сколько раз нажать на `выполнить код`

Comment: Извините, изначально я криво задал вопрос. Визуальный шум появляющийся при hover – анимированный,  Как они реализовали этот самый анимированный шум, в этом вопрос, именно это непонятно.

Comment: это в svg делается - есть такой фильтр feTurbulense , здесь в разделе svg есть вопрос "Как сделать эффект воды" вот собственно там есть реализация - я просто под svg path положил gif

Comment: Благодарю, вопрос для меня стал понятней.

Comment: если хочешь я скину тебе пример как я это сделал на css , только картинки  меня не в интернете и тому могу скинуть только архив

Comment: Да, конечно, если не жалко :)

Comment: email напиши свой

Comment: dupre1473@mail.ru

Comment: отправил пример

Comment: Посмотрю и после отпишу